# Conceptually, how do I write my flux Stores to not mix up unrelated data together?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

Let's assume I have an application that relies on Flux.

Most Flux tutorials tells you that your `Components` should listen to a `change` event on a `Store` and render the data accordingly. This approach is great for small and simple use cases, however I have an issue in just a slightly more complex scenario:

I have a list of customers which I can filter by city of residence (Washington, New York, and so on). This list is available under the url `/customers/by-city` and could be represented by the following code:

```js
var CustomersList = React.createClass({
 
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      city: 'Washington',
      customers: []
    };
  },
 
  componentWillMount: function() {
    CustomersActions.retrieveForCity(this.state.city);
    CustomersStore.on('change', this.handleNewData);
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    CustomersStore.off('change', this.handleNewData);
  },

  render: function() {
    return <FilteredTable filters={['city']}
                          onCityChange={this.handleCityChange} 
                          data={this.state.customers} />;
  },

  handleCityChange: function(state) {
    CustomersActions.retrieveForCity(this.state.city);
    this.setState({city: city});
  },
  
  handleNewData: function(customers) {
    this.setState({customers: customers});
  }

});
```

Every time I want to filter by a different city, an AJAX request is issued by `CustomersActions`, response goes to `Dispatcher`. `CustomersStore` then picks it up, stores as it's `data`, and a issues a `change` event. Pretty much standard Flux stuff.

Now, as far as I understand, there is no way to tie that `change` event to what it actually did. So imagine the following scenario:

- I filter the table by `San Francisco`
- I change my mind and before the AJAX request is completed, I click on some navigation link (handled by react, no page reloads) and I end up on a different url, e.g. `/customers/shortlisted`. There is another component available under this URL: `ShortlistedCustomers`.
- `ShortlistedCustomers` is similar to `CustomersList` - in order to display the data it issues an ajax request via `CustomerActions` and listens to `change` event on `CustomersStore`
- Now the trick part - the second ajax request is completed before the first one, two `change` events are issued and user ends up with the wrong data in his table

How do I solve this "properly"? I am interested in the simplest solution possible, maybe something recommended by FB guys themselves? I realize I could e.g. cancel the first AJAX, or only handle responses in the same order those requests were issued, but this will quickly get out of hand.

Note this question is not specific to this case, but it's a more general question. E.g. the solution should apply if I want to add more ways to trigger an AJAX request, or more Components relying on the same Store.

Comment: "I go to another component in my application" --- how this "go" is represented actually?

Comment: I updated my question - this "go" could be something like react-router or similar; no page reloads if that's what you mean

Comment: "In your current code you start with an object with 2 attributes, then you replace it with an object with one attribute." first argument to `setState()` is a diff, not a new state; so it's merged into the existing state

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html `setState() Performs a shallow merge of nextState into current state`

Comment: Oh gosh I always thought it substitutes the whole object every time :-S apologies

Answer (score 4):

Of course there are several viable approaches to this situation, each with their own pros and cons. Here's a few that I think would still comply with Flux.

Keep in mind, I don't know the full scope of your app, so some of these might just not be feasible for you.

**CustomersStore Listens for a Dispatched API Request Action**

1. An action is dispatched to indicate the API request was sent
2. CustomersStore clears its state when this action gets dispatched

Can also be useful for creating a loading state.

**CustomersStore stores its responses in buckets**

1. Data requested for the /by-city endpoint gets stored in CustomersStore under a 'byCity' hash.
2. The components for /by-city now accesses its data by specifying this hash, such as CustomersStore.getData('byCity')
3. Data for /shortlisted is stored and retrieved the same way

Now you can maybe utilize some caching logic.

**Create an Action to Reset CustomersStore**

1. When the CustomersStore receives this "Reset" action, it will clear its stored data.
2. /by-city and /shortlisted components dispatch the "Reset" action during the appropriate lifecycle function.

This will help you handle this same problem within a single component too

These are few ideas, and I do believe they'll still obey Flux principles. Hope this is useful!

Comment: The "Buckets" approach makes sense, however it does not protect the user from same-bucket race conditions, e.g. I filter the CustomersList, go somewhere else, and return before the initial AJAX is finished

Answer (score 1):

In a more complex app you would probably do better using Reflux or Redux. With Reflux you can emit with parameters to let the control component route the data as needed.

```js
import Reflux from 'reflux';

import Actions from './Actions';
import AddonStore from './Addon.Store';
import MixinStoreObject from './Mixin.Store';

function _GotData(data) { this.data1 = data; BasicStore.trigger('data1'); }

let BasicStoreObject = {
 init() { this.listenTo(AddonStore, this.onAddonTrigger); },
 data1: {},
 listenables: Actions,
 mixins: [MixinStoreObject],
 onGotData1: _GotData,
 onAddonTrigger() { BasicStore.trigger('data2'); },
 getData1() { return this.data1; },
 getData2() { return AddonStore.data2; },
 getData3() { return this.data3; }
}
const BasicStore = Reflux.createStore(BasicStoreObject);
export default BasicStore;
```

```js
import React from 'react';

import BasicStore from './../flux/Basic.Store';

let AppCtrlSty = {
 height: '100%',
 padding: '0 10px 0 0'
}

const getState = () => {
 return {
  Data1: BasicStore.getData1(),
  Data2: BasicStore.getData2(),
  Data3: BasicStore.getData3()
 };
};

class AppCtrlRender extends React.Component {
  render() {
  let data1 = JSON.stringify(this.state.Data1, null, 2);
  let data2 = JSON.stringify(this.state.Data2, null, 2);
  let data3 = JSON.stringify(this.state.Data3, null, 2);
  return (
   <div id='AppCtrlSty' style={AppCtrlSty}>
    React 1.4 ReFlux with SuperAgent<br/><br/>
    Data1: {data1}<br/><br/>
    Data2: {data2}<br/><br/>
    Data3: {data3}<br/><br/>
   </div>
  );
 }
}

export default class AppCtrl extends AppCtrlRender {
 constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = getState();
 }

 componentDidMount() { this.unsubscribe = BasicStore.listen(this.storeDidChange.bind(this)); }
 componentWillUnmount() { this.unsubscribe(); }
 storeDidChange(id) {
  switch (id) {
   case 'data1': this.setState({Data1: BasicStore.getData1()}); break;
   case 'data2': this.setState({Data2: BasicStore.getData2()}); break;
   case 'data3': this.setState({Data3: BasicStore.getData3()}); break;
   default: this.setState(getState());
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ShortListedCustomers` and `CustomersList` should have/'grab their data' from separate stores [or separate properties from a common store]

Only the currently rendered component will re-render with data that is appropriate for it when the action/store triggers an event that data has arrived.

(this being said, I believe you should move to redux - even gradually - immutability and sequencing in the reducer(s) will help you think these kind of problems out)